# Pass by value and pointers

Tags: c, pass-by-value

Can you explain why the output is `3`?
I was trying to trace the answer and it shows that the line

```
i+=(a==b?1:0)
```

gives `1`, but doesn't `fun1()` pass **by value** so `q` and `p` were copied to different variables?

```
int fun1(int* a, int* b)
{
  int i = 0;
  i += (&a == &b ? 1 : 0);
  i += (a == b ? 1 : 0);
  i += (*a == *b ? 1 : 0);
  return i;
}
int fun2(int** a, int* b)
{
  int i = 0;
  i += (a == &b ? 1 : 0);
  i += (*a == b ? 1 : 0);
  return i;  
}
int main(void)
{
  int i = 0;
  int* p = &i;
  int* q = &i;

  printf("%d\n", fun1(p, q) + fun2(&p, q));
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `fun1`:

1. `(&a==&b?1:0)`

   This gives `0`.  They are two different arguments to `fun1`, basically two different local variables, so they cannot have the same address.
2. `(a==b?1:0)`

   This gives `1`.  The values are both `&i` from `main`.
3. `(*a==*b?1:0)`

   This gives `1`.  Since `a` and `b` are equal, they point to the same thing.

In `fun2`:

1. `(a==&b?1:0)`

   This gives `0`.  `a` and `b` are both arguments, so `a` can't equal the address of `b` (and in fact, it equals `&p` from main).
2. `(*a==b?1:0)`

   This gives `1`.  `a` is equal to `&p` from main, so `*a` is equal to `p` from main, which is `&i` from main.  And `b` is equal to `q` from main, which is again `&i` from main.

The total is therefore `3`.

Answer (score 1):

`a==b` is actually testing whether `a` and `b` points to same memory location or not. In function `fun1`, both `a` and `b` points to the same memory location and therefore `a==b` comes out to be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int fun1(int *a, int*b)
{
    int i=0;
    i+=(&a==&b?1:0); // 0. &a is the memory where a stands. it's different from &b.
    i+=(a==b?1:0); // 1. Both pointers point to the same memory.
    i+=(*a==*b?1:0); // 1. *a is the value where it points to, and that's the same as *b.
    return i; // returns 2

}
int fun2(int **a, int*b)
{
    int i=0;
    i+=(a==&b?1:0); // 0
    i+=(*a==b?1:0); // 1. *a is the value where it points to, and this is a memory value that is the same as b.
    return i; // returns 1

}
```

That's why it returns 3.

Good question, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider at first the first function

```
int fun1(int *a, int*b)
{
    int i=0;
    i+=(&a==&b?1:0);
    i+=(a==b?1:0);
    i+=(*a==*b?1:0);
    return i;
}
```

It was called like

```
fun1(p,q)
```

where the both pointers point to the same variable

```
int *p=&i;
int *q=&i;
```

So the function got two equal values as its argument. It is the address of variable `i`.

Function parameters are its local variable. You can imagine the called function like

```
int fun1( /*int *a, int*b */)
{
    int *a = p;
    int *b = q;
    //...
}
```

These local variables occupies different extents of memory. So `&a` is not equal to `&b`.

As result the value of expression `(&a==&b?1:0)` will be equal to 0 and variable `i` in the statement below

```
i+=(&a==&b?1:0);
```

will not be changed

The values stored in variables `a` and `b` id the address of variable `i` in `main`. As it was said early the two variables contain the same value.
So expression `(a==b?1:0)` will yield 1 and variable `i` in the statement below

```
    i+=(a==b?1:0);
```

will be increased.

As the both pointers points to the same object then expression `(*a==*b?1:0)` also will yield 1. As result variable `i` will be increased/

```
    i+=(*a==*b?1:0);
```

The function will return value 2.

Now let's consider the second function

```
int fun2(int **a, int*b)
{
    int i=0;
    i+=(a==&b?1:0);
    i+=(*a==b?1:0);
    return i;
}
```

As it was said above parameter `b` is a local variable of the function. Its address does not equal to the address of argument `p`

So expression `(a==&b?1:0)` yields 0.

Expression `*a` is the value stored in argument `p` The same value is stored in parameter `b`

So expression `(*a==b?1:0)` yields 1.

In total the sum of the return values of the functions will be equal to 3.